# Why would a for loop cause a hang when a while loop works fine?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

After spending some time looking through my functions to figure out what the issue was, I realised that an instance of a `for` loop was causing a hang when I called the function containing it.

The original code:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
    if (!this.fields[i].isValid()) return false;
}

return true;
```

The `isValid` method returns a boolean in all cases, and the fields property is an array containing objects.

Calling this code causes my page to hang. However, the following code works fine:

```
// Duplicate the array
var fields = this.fields.slice(0),
    field;

while (field = fields.shift()) {
    if (!field.isValid()) return false;
}

return true;
```

This is causing me quite some confusion.

Comment: Please `console.log(this.fields.length)` to see its value. What value does it output?

Comment: Also, an actual demo where we can reproduce the problem would be useful

Comment: returning false doesn't really do anything in that context, if you want to break, use `break`

Comment: @adeneo OP states it's in a function.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi It correctly outputs the length of the array, in this case 6

Comment: Will post a jsfiddle demo shortly

Comment: @DaveNewton - In that case, you don't really place the return statement for a function inside an if statement inside a for loop.

Comment: The control variable in the `for` loop is missing `var`, thus `i` may be global. Perhaps `isValid` contains another loop that changes `i`?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, but I'm asking about why the for loop might be causing a problem.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff That must be it. I'm using a lot of loops to iterate over various arrays. This is the only clash I encountered, though

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff I've cleared up my code and that was the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @adeneo That's an opinion, for me, short methods read more cleanly if you return as soon as you can.